# Symfony generate wrong directory

Tags: php, symfony

I have something strange with my project. When i want to generate a bundle with `php app/console generate:bundle`; He always generate in `app/cache` instead of `/src`. That not all, when i override **template** of `FOSUSerBundle` and i want to clear cache i got that error

```
"/Users/username/Desktop/dev/Symfony/app/cache/de_/../../Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig" resource is hidden by a resource from the "AcmeUserBundle" derived bundle. Create a "/Users/username/Desktop/dev/Symfony/app/cache/de_/../../Resources/AcmeUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig" file to override the bundle resource.
```

***why does /src is now app/cache ?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **fixed** with :

```
php composer.phar self-update
php composer self-update
```

**i thing composer clean the project and override path.**

Comment: I've also come across this same issue. Will try your solution.

Comment: No this didn't work for me on an existing project I've came across this on. The Target Directory is still pointing to: `Target directory [/var/www/html/Symfony/app/cache/dev/../src]:` instead of the `bundle/src`. Will again later on a fresh new project.